# android MediaRecorder.onInfoListener error codes

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am using `MediaRecorder.onInfoListener()` and I'm frequently getting error number `802` with varying `extra` information (on a Samsung Galaxy 1), but I don't know what to do with it as it isn't documented in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener.html). What is its meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From more looking around it seems an undocumented value. Better not rely on it,

Answer (score 0):

I have not found documentation listing error code 802.  The following page lists the error codes 1, 800, 801, and 1.  I do not know if the second entry of 1 is a typo.  That might be your error 802...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html